# how to debug kvm to avoid endless restart

Tags: debugging, kvm

How to debug kvm? I'm going to do some change to kvm, and it is common to crash and needs to restart. How to make it easier? kgdb or nested virtualization?
(1) what's the right/mature way
(2) are there any posts

Comment: I have tried the nested virtualization way, and combined with gdb (with hbreak), a good way to take practice. But it doesn't apply to my requirement. My situation is debugging kvm-intel's EPT. And for now, nested EPT (EPT on EPT) is only supported by 64bit guest hypervisors, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853212/when-using-kvm-nested-ept-shadow-vmcs-cannot-be-enabled). Turn to KGDB now...